# Truncate a dynamic value using Java8

Tags: java, java-8, substring, truncate

In one of my application I used to get some reference number like as shown below

```
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4444..0
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4445..1
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4446
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4446..5
:
:
```

How do I truncate the ending ..[n] if it contains in Java like as shown below. If it is a constant number I would have substring it like `.substring(0, value.indexOf("..0"))`, since the number is dynamic should I use Regex?

```
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4444
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4445
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4446
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4446
:
:
```

Can someone please help me on this

Comment: Or you could simply use .substring(0, value.indexOf("..")), assuming there are no other occurrences of ".." in your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement here:

```java
String input = "BRD.2323-6984-4532-4444..0";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\.\\.\\d+$", "");
System.out.println(input);   // BRD.2323-6984-4532-4444..0
System.out.println(output);  // BRD.2323-6984-4532-4444
```

Note that the above replacement won't alter any reference number not having the two trailing dots and digit.

Comment: Thanks for thee quick reply. Will this takes care if it comes with more than single digit like for example  ..10

Comment: @AlexMan Yes, it will, try the code out to verify this.

Comment: Why `replaceAll` and not `replaceFirst`?

Comment: @Holger Would you believe it if I told you that I've never used `String#replaceFirst`?  Actually, performance wise it shouldn't matter here, since the regex pattern I used is scoped to only make a replacement at the end of the input.  But, you are correct and I agree with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that one of them, when modified, would result in a duplicate.  Here is something that might prove useful using [@TimBiegeleisen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) answer.  It will eliminate duplicates.

```
List<String> values = List.of(
        "BRD.2323-6984-4532-4444..0",
        "BRD.2323-6984-4532-4445..1",
        "BRD.2323-6984-4532-4446",
        "BRD.2323-6984-4532-4446..5");
UnaryOperator<String> modify = str->str.replaceAll("\\.\\.\\d+$", "");
Set<String> set = values.stream()
        .map(modify::apply)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

set.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4444
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4445
BRD.2323-6984-4532-4446
```

Comment: There’s no point in writing `.map(modify::apply)` when you can just write `.map(modify)`.